# Is there a more concise way to remove a top level JSON property using Argonaut?

Tags: json, scala, zipper, argonaut

Let's say I have this little [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io) `Json` instance:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

Json.obj(
  "id"     := 42,
  "viewed" := false
)
```

Now, I want to remove the pair whose key is `viewed`. I found the following to work, but it's a bit too verbose. Is there anything shorter than this:

```
for {
  field   <- json.cursor.downField("viewed")
  updated <- field.delete
} yield updated.undo
```

Also, the name of the method that "commits" the changes (`undo`) seems a bit misleading in my opinion? How should I interpret the name? Initially I thought there's a way to undo the last change in the history of modifications.

#### UPDATE

I have found one solution. Using an `HCursor`:

```
json.hcursor.downField("viewed").delete.undo
```

The question of why `undo` is named `undo` is still open though.

Comment: As a side note, there are operator aliases for most of the methods you're using: `-(!(json.acursor --\ "viewed"))`. And about `undo`: it kind of makes sense on the model of Anti-XML's `unselect`—you're not undoing the modifications, you're undoing the navigation into the tree.

Comment: @TravisBrown thanks. I know about the operator aliases, I just don't want to shock my coworkers (too much). Regarding `undo`... ok, now I can see why it might be named like that, but boy, it reads really wrong. Normally one would assume it undoes the last operation. For example, `downField("X").downField("Y").undo.undo` should go back to where I was initially. Bad naming IMHO. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is floating/moving reference like a pointer in C/C++.
And *downField* is move instruction to the cursor, therefore if you don't *undo* cursor remains in "viewed" propety instead of parent json object.
To return to parent json object, you have to *undo* to move cursor.